# How can I setup iis with an ssl cert?

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-6

Is there a way to programaticaly install a ssl cert for iis 6 and 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah try IIS 6.0 Resource Kit Tools: 
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=56fc92ee-a71a-4c73-b628-ade629c89499&displaylang=en

It includes a tool called: IISCertDeploy.vbs. This is a tool for deploying and for backing up SSL certificates on servers that run IIS 6.0. You can use IISCertDeploy.vbs to deploy the certificate to a local server, to a cluster of servers, or to a remote server. You can also use IISCertDeploy.vbs to back up a certificate by exporting the certificate from a Web site to a Personal Information Exchange (.pfx) file that contains both the private key and the public key.

Comment: Do you happen to know if it supports iis 7 as well?

Comment: I am not sure about that but you can make alot SSL staff directly from IIS 7 Manager in the "Administrative Tools". Check this link for creating Self-Signed SSL Certificate in IIS7: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/06/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates.aspx